# Open GUI while algo is running in the background

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, schedule, pysimplegui

I am attempting to keep Output running in the background while having an open GUI.

The GUI displays the finding from the Algo just fine. But it does not continue to run in the background.

Also, I am trying to get the Output to repeat from new, not continue.

Hope you can help.

```
Output = Output[Output['Match_Acc.'] >= 1]

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

font = ('Areal', 11)
sg.theme('BrownBlue')

data = Output

headings = ['Result', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

headings = df.columns.tolist()
data = df.values.tolist()

layout = [[sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],
         [sg.Button('Run'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

sg.Window("Overview", layout).read(close=True)

def job(): 
    Output
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried to move the schedule.run on the end and the start and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Window closed after statement `sg.Window("Overview", layout).read(close=True)`. With method `window.hide()` to hide the window, `window.un_hide` to show the window again.

```py
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def algo(window):
    global running
    while running:
        sleep(5)                                                    # The code for algo
        window.write_event_value('Algo Data', randint(0, 4))        # Event to update GUI
    window.write_event_value('Algo Done', None)                     # Event to close GUI

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
]

sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
layout = [
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('OK')],
]
window = sg.Window("ALGO", layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
running = True                                                      # Flag to quit Algo
threading.Thread(target=algo, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()  # Run algo in thread

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        # Close button to confirm if exit
        if sg.popup_yes_no("Are you sure to exit ?", title='Warning') == 'Yes':
            # Stop thread first
            running = False
        else:
            continue

    elif event == 'OK':
        # Hide GUI
        window.hide()

    elif event == 'Algo Data':
        index = values[event]
        window.un_hide()
        window['-TABLE-'].update(select_rows=[index])

    elif event == 'Algo Done':
        # Thread end
        break

window.close()
```